# Adding conditional div class to Genesis shortcode entry-header

Tags: php, css, shortcode, genesis

I am desperately trying to find a solution to add a conditional div class to individual categories when using the Genesis shortcode [post_categories] in the entry-header.

I want to apply unique colors to category titles in the entry header for articles on the home page and on individual posts. www.mic.com has this affect. You will notice that articles under the "World" category have the category text one color, while articles under the "News" category have the category text displayed as a different color.

For example, if the category is "Infrastructure", I'd like there to be a class that wraps around the existing entry-categories class.

I want it to look like this:

```
<div class="infrastructure section"><span class="entry-categories"></span></div>
```

If the category is "Elections", I'd like it to show:

```
<div class="elections section"><span class="entry-categories"></span></div>
```

The code I need to edit to get this effect is listed below.

```
add_shortcode( 'post_categories', 'genesis_post_categories_shortcode' );
/**
 * Produces the category links list.
 *
 * Supported shortcode attributes are:
 *   after (output after link, default is empty string),
 *   before (output before link, default is 'Tagged With: '),
 *   sep (separator string between tags, default is ', ').
 *
 * Output passes through 'genesis_post_categories_shortcode' filter before returning.
 *
 * @since 1.1.0
 *
 * @param array|string $atts Shortcode attributes. Empty string if no attributes.
 * @return string Shortcode output
 */
function genesis_post_categories_shortcode( $atts ) {

$defaults = array(
    'sep'    => ', ',
    'before' => __( 'Filed Under: ', 'genesis' ),
    'after'  => '',
);

$atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'post_categories' );

$cats = get_the_category_list( trim( $atts['sep'] ) . ' ' );

if ( genesis_html5() )
    $output = sprintf( '<span %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry-categories' ) ) . $atts['before'] . $cats . $atts['after'] . '</span>';
else
    $output = '<span class="categories">' . $atts['before'] . $cats . $atts['after'] . '</span>';

return apply_filters( 'genesis_post_categories_shortcode', $output, $atts );

}
```

I have tried using the get_the_category_list function to conditionally create the class names, but the  command is not completing an action. When viewing my site through firebug, the new class shows the  command as text.

```
$cats = get_the_category_list( trim( $atts['sep'] ) . ' ' );

if ( genesis_html5() )
    $output = sprintf( '<div class="<?php echo $cats[0]->cat_name; ?> section"><span %s>', genesis_attr( 'entry-categories' ) ) . $atts['before'] . $cats . $atts['after'] . '</span></div>';
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this affect?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work ( but only for html5 ):

```
function custom_terms_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $defaults = array(
                    'after'    => '',
                    'before'   => __( 'Filed Under: ', 'genesis' ),
                    'sep'      => ', ',
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    );

    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $atts, 'custom_terms' );

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), $atts['taxonomy'] );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) )
                    return;

    if ( empty( $terms ) )
                    return;

    if ( genesis_html5() ){


            $output .= '<span class="entry-terms">';
            $output .= $atts['before'];
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $output = '<div class="'. $term->name .'">';
            $output .= '<a href="'.esc_attr(add_query_arg( $atts['taxonomy'], $term->slug ),'').'">'.$term->name.'</a>'.$atts['sep'];
            $output .= '</div>';
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, -2);
            $output .= $atts['after'];
            $output .= '</span>';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'genesis_post_terms_shortcode', $output, $terms, $atts );

}
```